# SubprocVecEnv not working with Custom Env (Stable Baselines - Gym)

Tags: subprocess, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I've made a custom env using gym.Env as parent class and everything works well running single core. I've started the code as follows:

```
class MyEnv(gym.Env):
....
```

But if I try to use SubprocVecEnv to accelerate the learning process using all my 24 CPU cores, I receive the message:
*ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (24,24) into shape (24,1)*

I've tested DummyVecEnv and it works well, but as this function doesn't allow Multiprocessing, I would like to use SubprocVecEnv as I usually do with Atari/Gym envs.

PS: my custom env is very simple, basically I'm using a dataset with 567 rows and 4 columns, the agent visits one row at time and predicts two values from this observation. The observation_space and action_space are as follows:

```
self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=1, high=1, shape=(1,4), dtype=np.float64)

self.action_space = spaces.Box(low=np.array([0., -1.]), high=np.array([2., 1.]), dtype=np.float64)
```

I'm training the agent using PPO2 from stable baselines as I usually do.

Am I missing something important?

Answer (score 4):

For me, it was related to the input "start_method".

The default is 'forkserver', but on my machine it only worked with 'fork'

```
envs= [make_env(env_name, seed) for seed in range(nproc)]

envs = SubprocVecEnv(envs, start_method='fork')
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. But a problem arose:

Now in the `env.step()` function, the actions are only scalars, instead of vectors. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Check this sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import gym
from baselines.common.vec_env.subproc_vec_env import SubprocVecEnv

env_name = 'your-env-name'
nproc = 8
T=10

def make_env(env_id, seed):
    def _f():
        env = gym.make(env_id)
        env.seed(seed)
        return env
    return _f

envs= [make_env(env_name, seed) for seed in range(nproc)]

envs = SubprocVecEnv(envs)

Xt = envs.reset()

for t in range(T):
    ut = np.stack([envs.action_space.sample() for _ in range(nproc)])
    xtpl, rt, done, info = envs.step(ut)
```

Comment: maybe need register first

Comment: He said that everything works well running on a single core !