# Using SubprocVecEnv in SB3 results in "cannot pickle 'weakref' object" error, even though the same vectorized env works for DummyVecEnv. Why?

Tags: error-handling, stable-baselines

For multiprocessing I want to use the suggested vec_env_cls, SubprocVecEnv. Using it like the env-line in the given code below or also as vec_enc_cls=SubprocVecEnv in make_vec_env result both in an error of an unpicklable object.

```
    def create_envs(self, n_envs, eval_env: bool = False):
        """
        Creates environment vector.
        """        
        # Initialize parameters for a Custom Environment
        self.env_kwargs = {**config.ENV_PARAMS(self.env_id.lower()), "save_folder": self.save_path}

        env = SubprocVecEnv([self.make_env(i) for i in range(n_envs)])
#        env = make_vec_env(lambda: config.ENV_ID[self.env_id.lower()](**self.env_kwargs), n_envs=n_envs)
        if self.normalize and n_envs > 0:
            env = self._normalize_envs(env, eval_env)
        return env
```

Error:

```
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)

TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Calculations\anaconda3\envs\laue\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\Calculations\anaconda3\envs\laue\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

I tried to find a similar Issue on the SB3 github Repo but didn't found anything. And this is also not a solution.
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65726221/subprocvecenv-not-working-with-custom-env-stable-baselines-gym)

Does anyone know what could cause such an error? I am in general not familiar with the weakref's and what from my env could be labelled as such.

Best.